# Custom sorting of objects by key in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sorting, angularjs-orderby

I have an object stored in $scope.addresscards inside a controller. The js is given below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.addresscards = {
      "work_address": {
          "location":"workLoc",
          "address": "workAddr",
          "flat_no": "worknumber",
          "landmark": "workLandmark"
      },
      "random1_address": {
          "location":"someLoc",
          "address": "SomeAddr",
          "flat_no": "Somenumber",
          "landmark": "someLandmark"
      },
      "home_address": {
          "location":"homeLoc",
          "address": "homeAddr",
          "flat_no": "homenumber",
          "landmark": "homeLandmark"
      },
      "random2_address": {
          "location":"someLoc2",
          "address": "SomeAddr2",
          "flat_no": "Somenumber2",
          "landmark": "someLandmark2"
      }
  };
}
```

I'm using ng-repeat to display the addresses. Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="(addressKey,addressVal) in addresscards">
     <li>{{addressKey}} has :: {{addressVal.location}},{{addressVal.address}}, {{addressVal.location}}, {{addressVal.address}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My output is:

```
home_address has :: homeLoc, homeAddr, homeLoc, homeAddr
random1_address has :: someLoc, SomeAddr, someLoc, SomeAddr
random2_address has :: someLoc2, SomeAddr2, someLoc2, SomeAddr2
work_address has :: workLoc, workAddr, workLoc, workAddr
```

I want to display the output such that, if the object has home_address it should be displayed 1st, then if the object has work_address it should be displayed. Then rest of the object should be showed alphabetically.

Here is expected result that I want to display:

```
home_address has :: homeLoc, homeAddr, homeLoc, homeAddr
work_address has :: workLoc, workAddr, workLoc, workAddr
random1_address has :: someLoc, SomeAddr, someLoc, SomeAddr
random2_address has :: someLoc2, SomeAddr2, someLoc2, SomeAddr2
```

I tried it using orderBy, It doesn't work on objects. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your address objects

```
$scope.addresscards = {
      "work_address": {
          "location":"workLoc",
          "address": "workAddr",
          "flat_no": "worknumber",
          "landmark": "workLandmark",
          "sort" : "2"
      },
      "random1_address": {
          "location":"someLoc",
          "address": "SomeAddr",
          "flat_no": "Somenumber",
          "landmark": "someLandmark"
      },
      "home_address": {
          "location":"homeLoc",
          "address": "homeAddr",
          "flat_no": "homenumber",
          "landmark": "homeLandmark",
          "sort" : "1"
      },
      "random2_address": {
          "location":"someLoc2",
          "address": "SomeAddr2",
          "flat_no": "Somenumber2",
          "landmark": "someLandmark2"
      }
  };
```

and in your ng-repeat you can orderBy multiple fields first by sort to display home and work address first and then by address key for alphabetical order.

```
  <ul ng-repeat="(addressKey,addressVal) in addresscards | orderBy:['sort','addressKey']">
     <li>{{addressKey}} has :: {{addressVal.location}},{{addressVal.address}}, {{addressVal.location}}, {{addressVal.address}}</li>
  </ul>
```

or in your controller you can sort all other addresses and append home and work address to the beginning of your list.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5BU6KUp9QhdI6AJRzk7x)

Comment: I tried this, it is not working. I'm getting output like this: `{{addressKey}} has :: {{addressVal.location}}, {{addressVal.address}}, {{addressVal.location}}, {{addressVal.address}}
{{}}`

Comment: It is because you are getting an error, can you share the error in console please.

Comment: The error was due to a missing ',' in the object. removed the error but still it's not sorting. I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: It is because your address cards are not array, I am adding a working plunker for you

Comment: I moved the keys into an array and sorted the array. then used the array for ng-repeat. then mapped addresscards with the key.